# How can I shuffle unique key values on a dimension table?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

Using the following table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test 
(
    [ID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [Code] CHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
);
```

For the sake of de-identifying a data set, I need to randomize the code values.

I would like to preserve the ID values, so that other tables need not change, as well.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT t.ID, c.Code
FROM dbo.Test AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP(1) v.Code
             FROM dbo.Test AS v
             WHERE v.Code <> t.Code
             ORDER BY NEWID()) AS c
```

The issue was that the same unique key value would be assigned to multiple records.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Does adding a TOP (1) to your subquery get you what you need?

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be there. I copied the query manually from another machine, but missed it. Updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
-- Sample data
DECLARE @test TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, [Code] CHAR(10));
INSERT @test
VALUES (REPLICATE('A',10)),(REPLICATE('B',10)),(REPLICATE('C',10)),(REPLICATE('D',10));

-- Solution
SELECT t.ID, c.[Code]
FROM   @test AS t
JOIN   
(
  SELECT SK = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()), t.[Code]
  FROM   @test AS t
) AS c ON c.SK = t.ID;
```

**Returns:**

```
ID          Code
----------- ----------
1           DDDDDDDDDD
2           AAAAAAAAAA
3           BBBBBBBBBB
4           CCCCCCCCCC
```

(but your results may be different - which is the point)

**QUICK UPDATE:**

Note that if your IDs are not sequential (e.g. some IDs have been deleted) then you may consider:

```
WITH T1 AS (SELECT t.ID, SK = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.ID) FROM @test AS t),
     T2 AS (SELECT SK = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()), t.[Code] FROM @test AS t)
SELECT t1.ID, t2.Code
FROM T1
JOIN T2 ON T1.SK = T2.SK;
```